# Condition in WHERE vs condition in CONNECT BY

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, where

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the following two queries? Even though they seem the same the results are different.

```
select concept.concept_id, concept.PARENT_ID 
from ebti_thes_concept_v concept
  start with PARENT_ID = '11025'
  connect by parent_id = prior concept_id
  and exists (..)
```

In the second one, the `exists` predicate is moved from the `connect by` clause to the `where` clause.

```
select concept.concept_id, concept.PARENT_ID
from ebti_thes_concept_v concept
where exists (..)
 start with PARENT_ID = '11025'
 connect by parent_id = prior concept_id;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702), I came to the following conclusions.

One difference between the two queries is that the first query has two condition in the `connect by` , in order to identify a relationship - a row must fulfill not only the `parent_id = prior concept_id` condition but also the `exists` clause.

```
 connect by parent_id = prior concept_id
 and exists (..)
```

While the second one has only one condition.

```
 connect by parent_id = prior concept_id;
```

The part of the query that makes the distinction more obvious is the `start with`.

In the first query, all the rows with `PARENT_ID = '11025'` will be returned and used as `root` rows. The two conditions of the `connect by` will be used to find the `children` of those rows. The `exists` condition will not be applied to the root rows.

On the other hand, the second query will fetch the rows with `PARENT_ID = '11025'` and filter them with the `exists` statement.

As a result, the results will be totally different.

Comment: Yes. The first query says *"find me the children of X and then all their blue descendants"* while the 2nd says *"find me the **blue** children of X and then all their blue descendants"* (where "blue" in the property checked in the subquery).